# javascript array to object transformation

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

i want to build an object using this code

```
$("input").bind("keydown",function(e){
 var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
 if (code == 13){
  var guess = $("input").val();
  guess = guess.split(" ");
  var oGuess = {};
  for (var x = 0; guess.length ; x++){
   oGuess[x] = oGuess[x] = {"text": guess[x]};
  }
  $("input").val("");
 }
});
```

this actually **crashes** my browsers(latest stable ff and chrome) upon hitting enter. heres the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kfqJC/1/

i need the object to be something like this

```
oGuess = {
"1": { "text" : string}
"2": { "text" : string}
...
}
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: for (var x = 0; guess.length ; x++) <= should be x < guess.length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop never terminates. If `guess` has one element or more, `guess.length` will always evaluate to `true`.

I assume you want

```
for (var x = 0; x < guess.length ; x++){
//              ^^^
```

Also, what is this for?

```
oGuess[x] = oGuess[x] = {"text": guess[x]};
```

Just write

```
oGuess[x] = {"text": guess[x]};
```

And if you want the properties start with `1`, you have to write

```
oGuess[x+1]
```

thought I don't see any advantage of using an object over an array in this case.

Comment: means "I guess you want `for (var x = 0, len = guess.length; x < len; x++) {` "

Comment: Why not use oGuess.push({"text":guess[x]}); ?

Comment: @Mithon: `oGuess` is an object, not an array, and therefore does not have a method `push`, unless you define it which is not the case here.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Of course you'd also have to change the initialization to var oGuess = []; but I didn't think I'd have to spell that out. Just seems weird to keep it an object when it's used like an array.

Comment: That's what I meant with *I don't see any advantage of using an object over an array in this case*. I don't know why the OP wants this.

Comment: i'm submitting the object to a node.js app and i'm using mongodb